# Как сделать вывод сообщений об ошибках сборки webpack на сайте

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, webpack

Сейчас у меня стоит watch, и webpack делает пересборку, после каждого изменения файла. Но когда я допускаю синтаксические ошибки в js, то в консоли вылетает ошибка и сборка не собирается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то сделать, что бы помимо ошибки в консоли отображалась бы ошибка и на сайте, т.е. что бы в бандл добавлялся бы какой нибудь alert, который, после обновления страницы, выводил бы сообщение об ошибке на сайте при возникновении ошибки сборки?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-notifier

Comment: @overthesanity оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach ссылка на пакет не является ответом

Comment: @overthesanity Вполне себе ответ, если вы еще приведете пример использования который поможет конкретно в этом вопросе это будет вообще идеальный ответ, но можно и просто ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже и указали в комментариях к вопросу есть плагин [Notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-notifier), который можно подключить:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...

  plugins: [
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
  ]
}
```